TSAN WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: unlock of an unlocked mutex (or by a wrong thread)
I have write the following member function in my class which executes in a seperate thread and it sets the _cancellationRequested to true and execution function which runs in a seperate thread detects that variable and cancel the execution and return.
All good in functionality. However I'm getting a TSAN warning as
TSAN WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: unlock of an unlocked mutex (or by a wrong thread)
at the end of the if block.
bool Sender::CancelRequest()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::timed_mutex> lock(_processMutex, std::try_to_lock);
    if (!lock.owns_lock())
    {
        _cancellationRequested = true;

        std::unique_lock<std::timed_mutex> timedLock(_processMutex, std::chrono::seconds(30));
        if (!timedLock.owns_lock())
        {
            // Unable to get the lock 
            return false;
        }

        return _cancelled;
    }

    // Cancellation Called without having a request
    return false;
}

Please help me in identifying how to fix it.

There are two std::unique_lock instances, and the ThreadSanitizer may not understand the condition around the call to owns_lock().  I would suggest changing the flow of the logic slightly; after the first lock instance, instead check if (lock.owns_lock()) and if so return false.  Otherwise proceed with the cancellation logic.

Thanks  @PhilBrubaker, I will try that way.

Please show a [mre]

#include 
#include 
int main()
{
std::timed_mutex mutex;
std::unique_lockstd::timed_mutex lock(mutex, std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

@AlanBirtles Even the above code TSAN gives same error

@PhilBrubaker No luck yet

The code you've shown isn't runnable so can't produce TSAN warnings, please show a [mre]

@SujithGunawardhane The full output from ThreadSanitizer might be helpful, too.
